# iterating over all the bookmarks in Bookmarks.plist

Tags: python, plist

The Bookmarks.plist file is how Safari stores its bookmarks. How do I count all URLStrings?

I can get the bookmarks file with:

`BOOKMARKS_PLIST = '~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`

convert it to text from binary with:

`converted = subprocess.call(['plutil', '-convert', 'xml1', bookmarksFileCopy])`

and for example, access a single entry with:

'print plist['Children'][5]['Children'][1]['Children'][2]'

It seems I should use recursion to walk down the 'leaves of the tree' but I cannot  get the syntax right in python. As you can tell, I am a beginner.

EDIT:
Thank you Jose. Although your solution gave the error I described below, I did get this to work:

```
import plistlib
import subprocess
import os

def countURLStrings(plistDict):
    childURLCounts = 0
    if 'Children' in plistDict.keys():
        for child in plistDict['Children']:
            childURLCounts += countURLStrings(child)
    if 'URLString' in plistDict.keys():
        childURLCounts += 1
        print plistDict.URLString
    return childURLCounts

BOOKMARKS_PLIST = '/Users/me/Desktop/Safari-20150403175048/Bookmarks.plist'
converted = subprocess.call(['plutil', '-convert', 'xml1', BOOKMARKS_PLIST])

pl = plistlib.readPlist(BOOKMARKS_PLIST)

ct = countURLStrings(pl)

print ct
```

And as a bonus, this iterated version is faster than the recursion I tried and failed at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code example works in Python 3.4.2.  The load() method is not available in 2.x and the readPlist() method encounters an error. The second code example was tested successfully with Python 2.7.6.

BOOKMARKS_PLIST

- Replace username in the definition of (BOOKMARKS_PLIST) with the correct username
- The method provided [countURLStrings(plistDict)] recursively calls itself with every encountered instance of a 'Children' dictionary and increases the count by one for every 'URLString' encountered.

Sample Code Python 3.4.2

```
import plistlib

def countURLStrings(plistDict):
    childURLCounts = 0
    if 'Children' in plistDict.keys():
        for child in plistDict['Children']:
            childURLCounts += countURLStrings(child)
    if 'URLString' in plistDict.keys():
        childURLCounts += 1
    return childURLCounts

BOOKMARKS_PLIST = '/Users/username/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist'

with open(BOOKMARKS_PLIST, 'rb') as fp:
    pl = plistlib.load(fp)

countURLStrings(pl)
```

Sample Code Python 2.7.6

```
import biplist

def countURLStrings(plistDict):
    childURLCounts = 0
    if 'Children' in plistDict.keys():
        for child in plistDict['Children']:
            childURLCounts += countURLStrings(child)
    if 'URLString' in plistDict.keys():
        childURLCounts += 1
    return childURLCounts

BOOKMARKS_PLIST = '/Users/jaburaschi/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist'

with open(BOOKMARKS_PLIST, 'rb') as fp:
    pl = biplist.readPlist(fp)

countURLStrings(pl)
```

Comment: Thank for your contribution (although I don't know why you gave me a -1; I am still a noob ). I tried the second code sample (since I am using anaconda v 2.2 ( it uses python2.79). There was no biplist package so I installed it with pip. Then I get this error:

Comment: File "/Users/me/PyProjects/pylisterP/pylister3.py", line 15, in <module>
  pl = biplist.readPlist(fp)
File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biplist/__init__.py", line 126, in readPlist
  raise InvalidPlistException(e)

biplist.InvalidPlistException: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

Comment: sorry about the poor formatting, i cannot get new lines or code highlighting in comments

Comment: I guess the safari bookmarks plist has characters that biplist does not like.

Comment: Good question.  I have **2922** URLs in my plist and it ran successfully in **3.4.2** and **2.7.6** with the code samples above.  I received a similar error when I tried using the **plistlib** library and **plistlib.readPlist** function in **2.7.6**.  Note a couple of assumptions:  - The initial request was to parse the Safari plist - /Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist  - The Safari plist is binary and if you created a plist with a text editor the approach may have to be different.

Comment: Have you tried the code with the Safari plist?  If you have not tried to run the code with the Safari plist could you try it?  

If you have created your own plist then you can try import plistlib and using  plistlib.readPlist instead of biplist.readPlist.